# DHCP lease issue Windows 7 pro x64

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, dhcp, desktop-computer

**The Issue**

I am having a DHCP lease issue with one of my desktops, instead I am getting an APIPA IP assigned instead.

**Background**

It's a brand new computer (HP ProDesk 400 G3).  I bought it about a months ago, it's a replacement for someone's PC in our office.  Everything worked just fine from the start, I was able to install updates, install softwares (I usually install it from a server), no problem.  But right before I was to do the last thing (Windows Easy Transfer), I started to get APIPA IP on this computer.

It is Windows 7 pro x64 machine.

**What was done**

- I tried the following commands:

> ipconfig /release
>
> ipconfig /renew
>
> ipconfig /flushdns
>
> netsh int ip reset

- I tried physically assigning static IP.
- I tried making a DHCP reservation on the DHCP server.
- I tried restoring Windows to a previous state (about 3 weeks prior to APIPA issue).
- I tried uninstalling/disabling NIC.
- I tried disabling IPv6.
- I tried stopping/starting DHCP services.
- I tried changing NIC from Autonegotiation to 100/10/1 full/duplex.
- I tried rolling the NIC driver back.

It's not the cable(s), as I used/still using the same cable for my laptop and I get full access to the network/internet.

I am running out ideas...

**Additional Info**

The only thing I could possibly think, that might have interfered with anything is a scanner (HP ScanJet Pro 2500 fl) that was installed.  But even after removing it, it still did not help.

- No WiFi on this desktop.
- All the drivers are up-to-date.

Ask away, if you need more info.

**Help!**

**Update 24.VIII.2016 @ 11.18**

Here are the [Wireshark results](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzAL2CUzCS8fekpHOUo3M2lqdmc) (txt file).  For privacy I subbed any references to server, computer and DC with (server, computer and domain).

**Update 24.VIII.20016 @ 11.59**

So I was able to access Internet as well as network resources after booting up with Fedora Live CD.

 **Update 24.VIII.2016 @ 13.46**

@bvaughn, You might be onto something.  Here is a screenshot of the registry for NIC:
[image]

That does not look close to what my laptop looks like.

Comment: So your problem is that you're not getting a DHCP lease? APIPA in itself is a feature, not a problem, and that seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's the best way to put it.

Comment: What do you mean by "physically assigning the IP"? Did you try assigning a static IP? Did it work?

Comment: @Doezer Yes, sorry, static IP and no it did not.

Comment: It seems that you've covered pretty much all possible problems with your tests. I'd try to boot with a linux livecd (or liveusb) and see if the dhcp works.

Comment: Please start a capture of the traffic on the NIC (using Wireshark for example) then reboot the DHCP service (in admin, *net stop dhcp* then *net start dhcp*). You should see DHCP Discover requests.

Comment: @Doezer I will try that first

Comment: @DrNoone I will try that right after Wireshark

Comment: Is there a DHCP server log and what does it say?

Comment: @Doezer I just posted Wireshark results

Comment: @DudenamedBen There is, no errors, warnings or critical messages.  The messages I get are "DHCPc4 client service is started"

Comment: @DrNoone I booted it up with Federo Live CD and I am able to get online and get to the network resources...  Should I just re-installed Windows at this point?

Comment: Sounds like - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/unable-to-aquire-dhcp-address-on-windows-7/234c6cdb-14b8-4577-a095-e139130a0c1a?auth=1 & https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/teamdhcp/2009/02/12/dhcp-broadcast-flag-handling-in-windows-7/

Comment: Your wireshark had both tcpip 4 & 6th. If this is a home setup, only one should be enabled. Then see if can ping the router. With a static ip on the correct subnet, you should be able to do it. If not, then points to a windows driver issue for your nic or you have the software firewall set to something odd. etc.

Comment: @bvaughn I disabled IPv6 and it's not home setup. Even after putting static IP in, it's still gives me APIPA address.

Comment: Since this is a domain environment, the question is off topic here at SU.

Comment: @Moab, I would agree with you if I was asking about network or server.  The issue is related to a single computer and its inability to obtain a lease from DHCP server.  But if people feel that this question should not be on SU, but rather on serverfault, it can be moved.

Comment: static and APIPA are exclusive.  what is ip address, gateway, and subnet while using fedora. From this info, what the correct static settings should be can be deduced. If your PC does not work with a correct static then have a general network issue, most likely driver. It would not be a DHCP issue. If static works, but then switch to DHCP fails, then have have a get DHCP address issue.

Comment: @bvaughn I have removed and updated the NIC drive.  In Fedora Live CD, I get correct subnet, getaway and appropriate IP issued.  Even when I assign static IP in Windows, I still get APIPA IP and obviously can't ping anything on the network or out.

Comment: @George domain networks are off topic here regardless of the issue.